# trying to advance from java to Python with no luck

Tags: python, for-loop

so i want to write this simple java code in python, but i cant, i want to print all the Strings letters form the first index to the last, so if my string is "josh", i want to print:

```
j 
o 
s
h
```

or like this java code:

```
   String name = josh;
   for(int i = 0; i < josh.length(); i++){
   print(josh.CharAt(i));
 }
```

i cant find any method that is like charAt, i'm guessing that it doesn't exists
but there has to some other way to do it, i know its kinda dumb question, but i couldn't
find anything online or here(on this website) to help me, so any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the concept of 'iterables' in Python. As per Preet's answer, you can treat a string as a list of characters. Alternatively, the equivalent to charAt() is the list offset: josh[0]=="j".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
name = "josh"
for i in name:
    print i
    # print(i) # python 3
```

`name` is the variable to which we assign string literal `"josh"`. name is a `str` (or `unicode` in Python 3)

we iterate over `name` since strings are iterable (have `__iter__()` methods) with the loop iteration syntax. Each consecutive character is assigned to loop variable `i` per iteration over `name`'s length.

Note that we cannot assign to `name[i]`, only read from it since strings are immutable in python.

Comment: or print(i) for python 3.x

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: It is worth noting why this works - Python `for` loops loop over iterables, and strings are iterables that return each character in turn.

Comment: Such simple code does not need any explanation...not even for Java kiddies

Comment: so easy, but i cant get it

Comment: @user2799617 That's not a helpful response - if you are going to say it's obvious, then at least link to relevant docs or tutorials.

Comment: ohhh.... they are iterables.....got it

Comment: and i am a java kiddie, so what...just trying to learn no need to be mean

Comment: guys, this website is for pros and noobs too, i am just trying to learn, you were like me in some point, so give me a break!